# Problem with UIAlertController's Text field Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Here is my code. When I press "Download" button my "someVariable" global variable doesn't change. I tried to debug it in the debugger but couldn't find the issue.

```
@IBAction func addButtonPressed(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    
    let textField = UITextField()
    
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Download URL", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)
    
    alert.addTextField { (actionTextField) in
        actionTextField.placeholder = "Paste link here"
    }
    
    let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Download", style: .default) { (action) in
        self.someVariable = textField.text!
    }
    let secondAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
    
    alert.addAction(action)
    alert.addAction(secondAction)
    present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: `self.someVariable = textField.text!`, `let textField = UITextField()`, there is absolutely NO link between the variable `textField` you just created and the one present in the `UIAlertController`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Stackoverflow. Your `textField` in line 2 is what you're getting your `someVariable`'s new value from. I'm supposing you want to get the value from your alert's textField instead.

You can get reference from your alert's textField through your alert's `textFields` property, like so:

```
let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Download", style: .default) { (action) in
    guard let textField = alert.textFields?.first else { return }        
    self.someVariable = textField.text!
}
```